# CSS Animation flickering slightly

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-animations

I am trying to experiment with CSS Animation and made a simple page transition effect using only Css animation. The problem is when the animation completes, a slight flicker is created. Can you guys suggest some thing to fix this?

Codepen link- https://codepen.io/jake2917/pen/qyzxva?editors=1100

Here is the code.
The problem start when i try to center the h1 tag.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#line {
  border: 0.5px solid #130f40;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 50%;
  animation-name: run;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  transition: 0.1s ease-in;
}

#container1 {
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: #ff7979;
  position: absolute;
  top: -110%;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in;
  animation-name: cover1;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#container2 {
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: #ff7979;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -110%;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in;
  animation-name: cover2;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes run {
  from {
    width: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 99%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes cover1 {
  0% {
    top: -10%;
    opacity: 0;
    height: 0;
  }
  100% {
    top: 0%;
    opacity: 1;
    height: 50vh;
  }
}

@keyframes cover2 {
  0% {
    bottom: -110%;
    opacity: 0;
    height: 0;
  }
  100% {
    bottom: 0%;
    opacity: 1;
    height: 50vh;
  }
}

// ADDING THIS LINE MAKE IT FLICKER
#container1 h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="line"></div>
<div id="container1">
  <h1>hello there</h1>
</div>
<div id="container2">
  <h1>hello there</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it flickering in Microsoft EDGE ? Please try and let me know. at the moment I do not understand what is flickering

Comment: the text "hello there" is flickering.

Comment: I'm not seeing any flicker with either Chrome or Firefox. There is an effect where the animation seems to "snap" suddenly into a different position when it completes, but I see that effect with or without the centering.

Comment: its happening in my browser- i am using chrome on mac.

Comment: when both the div snap. the entire screen move a bit to the right

Comment: The flickering left right at the end of the animation ? the text is a little bit to the right at the animation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is flickering left right because you have a content that is more than 100% of the body, html.

In many browsers they are adding a scroll bar and it pushed the content to the left.

What you need to do is to add a simple css code `overflow: hidden`. This way the content will be hidden, the body remains 100% height and the browser won't add scrollbar;

```
body {
  overflow:hidden;
}
```